# Statistical distribution of firms by revenue in competitive market

Tags: reference-request, data-request, industrial-organisation

I would like to produce a simple distribution of competitive market firms based on  their revenues. I know the number of firms in the market `n`, the total market revenue `TR` and, therefore, also the average revenue per firm.

I had the idea that I could bin revenues and apply the Poisson distribution to populate a distribution of firms in the market based on revenue. For example, 2 firms with $0 - $2 M in revenues, 4 firms with $2 - $4 M in revenues, etc.

Is anyone familiar with any research regarding the distribution of firms' revenues in a competitive market that would provide guidance or confirmation of doing something like this?

Comment: Although I am not familiar with the topic, I would guess using the lognormal distribution would make more sense than Poisson.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by competitive market? In most theoretical models with free entry the firms have the same technology. As a result, in equilibrium they all have the same revenue.

Comment: In real life defining a precise product market is very difficult. Is coke on the same market as Pepsi? What about sparkling water? There are same consumers for whom these are substitutes. These is a subject of study in antitrust cases, but in those cases usually there are only a few big firms on a market, not enough to properly fit a distribution.